# How can I define socks proxy (`ssh -D`) in `~/.ssh/config` file?

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, port-forwarding

I now run this to have a `socks` proxy:

```
ssh -D1111 my_server
```

I want to add it to my `.ssh/config` file to `ProxyCommand` so that whenever I run `ssh my_server`, I can have a `socks` proxy.

I searched but did not find a proper answer.

This is what I tried so far:

```
Host my_server
  HostName IP
  User root
  Port 1994
  ProxyCommand ssh -D1111 %h:%p
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your try with `ProxyCommand` is a mistake.

[`ProxyCommand` acts as an alternative for the raw TCP connection](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ProxyCommand). It's useful in cases where you want the SSH connection (the one you're about to start) use *something else* than raw TCP when connecting to the server. It may be another SSH connection (a "manually defined" alternative to `ProxyJump`) or a more sophisticated contraption ([example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/669232/108618)).

Your command line

> ```
> ssh -D1111 my_server
> ```

specifies *nothing* like this. Remove the `ProxyCommand` line from your config.

[`-D` in the command line](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#D) corresponds to [`DynamicForward` in the config file](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#DynamicForward). Use this:

```
DynamicForward 1111
```